# Xamarin.iOS, OxyPlot How to convert UIColor to OxyColor

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot to plot bar charts in xamarin.ios project. I've to change the bar colors of the barchart and it seems it takes only OxyColor, and I'm getting #code from my back end.

```
series.Items.Add(new ColumnItem() { Value = Double.Parse(graph.valueList[i]), Color = OxyColors.Green });
```

How can I change the hex code to OxyColor. or even UIColor to OxyColor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OxyColor` has a `Parse` method, the string in the format "#FFFFFF00" or "255,200,180,50"

i.e:

```
OxyColor.Parse("#FFFF0000")
OxyColor.Parse("#FF0000")
OxyColor.Parse("255,0,0")
OxyColor.Parse("255,255,0,0")
```

Ref: https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/4db3c45a2acc86b7b11816462cb4f2850c709a11/Source/OxyPlot/Rendering/OxyColor.cs